# how to enhance efficiency of my query

Tags: mysql

I have such a query:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_id)
    FROM 1097_course_students_tbl
    WHERE course_cycl_id=id
      AND stts_id <> 8
      AND client_id IN(SELECT id FROM 1097_clients_tbl WHERE is_removed=0)
  ) AS cnt
FROM 1097_course_cycle_tbl
WHERE (course_id IN (SELECT id FROM 1097_courses_tbl WHERE is_removed=2))
ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

I need to make it more efficient because it takes too long

any suggestions ?

thanks

Comment: Yes: run that query through [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) and see what it complains about. Probably, your database needs some more indices

Comment: Without database structure? BTW I have bad assosiations with `courses_tbl`  and `clients_tbl ` ... it smell for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT cc.*,IFNULL(q.cnt,0) cnt
FROM 1097_course_cycle_tbl cс
JOIN 1097_courses_tbl с ON c.id=cc.course_id AND c.is_removed=2
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT cs.course_cycl_id,COUNT(DISTINCT cs.client_id) cnt
    FROM 1097_course_students_tbl cs
    JOIN 1097_clients_tbl c ON cs.client_id=c.id AND c.is_removed=0
    WHERE cs.stts_id<>8
    GROUP BY cs.course_cycl_id
  ) q
ON q.course_cycl_id=cс.id
ORDER BY cc.start_date DESC
```

I think `id` in `1097_courses_tbl` and `1097_clients_tbl` is primary key.
Therefore I replaced `IN` into `JOIN`.

And I converted the subquery from `SELECT` block wich executed for each rows into the subquery with `GROUP BY` which using in `LEFT JOIN`. Here it'll execute only one time and return all the necessary information.

Comment: join is better than IN ? I always thought JOIN is bad

Comment: I think  in this case it isn't important because the optimizer will replace `IN` into `JOIN`  most likely and final query will be the same. I prefer use `JOIN` if it's possible. But the correlated subquery in the `SELECT` block very often isn't optimal. I think in your query it slows down the query.